# pdoc3 tries to import non-python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, documentation

I am trying to autogenerate documentation with pdoc3. It throws errors whenever a script refers to a non-python file. For example, if I import

`dd01 = pd.read_excel('DataDictionary01.xlsx', index_col=0)`

I get

`ImportError: Error importing 'DATA.work_products.r_technology.stackdd': FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'DataDictionary01.xlsx'`

Is there a way of preventing this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

The error happens if the script has the reference to the non-python file outside of the

`if __name__ == '__main__':`

block, or if there is no such block at all.

So, the solution is to put any such reference into this block.